# Calling a method from a different threads

Tags: .net, multithreading

I upload file to the server asynchronously by this method:

```
public static void uploadFile(String filePath)
{
    ///.. some code here

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress> task = insertRequest.UploadAsync();
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        //.. t.Result.BytesSent(); returns number of bytes sent to the server
        uploadStream.Dispose();
    });
    timer1.Start();
}
```

I need to know the amount of bytes sent to the server:

> t.Result.BytesSent();

But I want to call this method every second in timer_Tick event, what should I do ? How to call this method from a different task ?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: every second?! Are you sure?!!!? but anyway you simply call the method: uploadFile(params here) from the tick event.

Comment: Does it fail if you call it like you would call it normally? I don't see why you would be able to write a threaded upload method and then you are not able to call it...

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas, I want to implement a progress bar of the uploaded file, that is the reason why I want to call it every second. Sorry, what is wrong with that ?